# How to get access to directory in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have create a new directory `Library` in path `App\Http`

When I try to use this path to load class `pagination`:

```
use App\Http\Library\Pagination;
```

Then IDE says that does not see path `Library`

Comment: Seem I need to register this path in configuration

Comment: you have to namespace it `namespace App\Http\Library`

Comment: Can I use some namespaces?

Comment: In addition to namespaces, you'll probably need to update your autoload file, `php composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to autoload this into class map. In **composer.json** put the class into classmap.
`"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/Http/Library/Pagination"
        ]
    },`

Then you update your autoload file `composer-dumpautoload` or `php artisan optimize`